# How to return previous window when X windows button is pressed in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window

I'm very new to python and I'm currently in the process of learning how to create a login system. While doing so, I encountered a problem wherein I need the previous window to open back up when the current window's x button is pressed.

I've tried editing this, but when I called it on other functions by writing it as 'on_close():', it gave me and error: `"NameError: name 'on_close' is not defined"`

```py
    def on_close():

         #custom close options, here's one example:

         close = messagebox.askokcancel("Close", "Would you like to close the program?")
         if close:
              root.destroy()

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",  on_close)
```

```py
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox

w = 300
h = 2

def register_user():
    global username_info
    global password_info

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    file = open(username_info+".txt", "w")
    file.write(username_info)
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(text = "Registration Success")

def register():
    global screen1
    screen.withdraw()
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Registration")
    screen1.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = " Please Enter Your Details Below*").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Username *").pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Password *").pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen1, text= "Register", height="1", width="10", command = register_user).pack()

def login():
    global screen2

    screen.withdraw()
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("HOT or SUPER HOT")
    screen2.geometry("500x400")
    on_close():

def main_Screen():

    global screen

    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("600x300")
    screen.title("Login System")

    Label(text = "Login System" , bg = "black", width = w , height = h, font = ("Calibri", 20) , fg = "white").pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", height = h, width = "30", command = login).place(x=50 , y=200)
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register" ,height = h, width = "30", command = register).place(x=320 , y=200)

    screen.mainloop()

main_Screen()

print("Hello World")




def on_close():
    screen2.withdraw()
    screen.update()
    screen.deiconify


screen2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)
```

Solved it thanks for the help 
What solved it was when i added the '`screen2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)` into the `def login()`:

Comment: put `def on_close()` before you run `main_Screen()` which runs `mainloop()` which blocks program - so code after `main_Screen()` is not executed and Python doesn't know function `on_close()`

Comment: I did what you said but another error came up , it says that 'screen2 is not defined'

Comment: you should put `screen2.protocol()` in function which create `screen2`

Comment: try `screen.lift()` after `screen.deiconify()`

Comment: My bad here is the error , `line 70, in <module>
    screen2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)
NameError: name 'screen2' is not defined`

Comment: You will need to declare `global` on every function you call `screen2` and any other local variables. An alternative is to use an object oriented approach, or OOP in short, that can handle the same by using class attributes instead of the `global` pollution.

Comment: if you moved `screen2.protocol()` before `main_Screen()` then it is executed at start when `screen2` doesn't exist yet. Put `screen2.protocol()` in `login()` after you create `screen2`

Comment: Got it, Thanks , Additional question do you know how to get the input on a textbox then add it into an sql database?

Comment: `Entry` has `.get()`, [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) has `.get(0, 'end')` to get all text. Later you have to use module for your database (sqlite3, mysql-connector, etc.) and use `cursor.execute(sql_query, arguments)`. Or use module which works with different databases (SQLAlchemy, peewee) and use classes/objects instead of SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by defining `on_close()` beforehand

```
from tkinter import*

w = 300
h = 2


def on_close():
    screen2.withdraw()
    screen.update()
    screen.deiconify()


def register_user():
    global username_info
    global password_info

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    file = open(username_info+".txt", "w")
    file.write(username_info)
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(text = "Registration Success")


def register():
    global screen1
    screen.withdraw()
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Registration")
    screen1.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = " Please Enter Your Details Below*").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Username *").pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Password *").pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen1, text= "Register", height="1", width="10", command = register_user).pack()


def login():
    global screen2

    screen.withdraw()
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("NO IDEA")
    screen2.geometry("500x400")
    on_close()


def main_Screen():

    global screen

    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("600x300")
    screen.title("Login System")

    Label(text = "Login System" , bg = "black", width = w , height = h, font = ("Calibri", 20) , fg = "white").pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", height = h, width = "30", command = login).place(x=50 , y=200)
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register" ,height = h, width = "30", command = register).place(x=320 , y=200)

    screen.mainloop()


main_Screen()

print("Hello World")

screen2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)
```

This may help by not giving error